# Wrong xml node accessed when using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, foreach

I have an xml file generated by Vector CANeds. This file contains information about CANopen Objects I want to read with my tool written in C#.

The (very basic) structure of the xml is as follows:

```
<ISO15745ProfileContainer xmlns="http://www.canopen.org/xml/1.0">
    <ISO15745Profile>
        <ProfileHeader></ProfileHeader>
        <ProfileBody xsi:type="ProfileBody_Device_CANopen"</ProfileBody>
    </ISO15745Profile>
    <ISO15745Profile>
        <ProfileHeader></ProfileHeader>
        <ProfileBody xsi:type="ProfileBody_CommunicationNetwork_CANopen"</ProfileBody>
    </ISO15745Profile>
</ISO15745ProfileContainer>
```

When I create an XmlNodeList with both ISO15745Profile nodes in it and loop through then i get a strange behaviour. By accessing the subnodes with explicit indexes, everything is as expected. When I am using xpath, allways the first node is used.

Code snippet:

```
const string filepath = "CANeds1.xdd";
const string s_ns = "//ns:";
var mDataXML = new XmlDocument();
mDataXML.Load(filepath);
var root = mDataXML.DocumentElement;
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(mDataXML.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("ns", root.Attributes["xmlns"].Value);

foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes) {
    Console.WriteLine("  " + node.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["xsi:type"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("  " + node.SelectSingleNode(s_ns + "ProfileBody", nsm).Attributes["xsi:type"].Value);
}
```

Console output:

```
  ProfileBody_Device_CANopen
  ProfileBody_Device_CANopen
  ProfileBody_CommunicationNetwork_CANopen
  ProfileBody_Device_CANopen
```

Since node references the 2nd node, the last output should be commNetwork to. 
Does somebody see my mistake? I have already tried to rename one of the "ISO15745Profile" nodes but this did not change the outcome. I may have messed up something with the namespace...

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work as well...

Comment: Try to change `s_ns` to `".//ns:"` to select a node relative to the current node.

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx: *`//` - Recursive descent; searches for the specified element at any depth. When this path operator appears at the start of the pattern, it indicates recursive descent from the root node.*  So you're searching the entire document.

Comment: @quanik: great, as easy as that. Thank you very much

Comment: @iMattView I added some more explanation in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595016/9145461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more explanation to the answer given in the comments:

The important point is the `//` XPath expression. The definition [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Recursive descent; searches for the specified element at any depth. When this path operator appears at the start of the pattern, it indicates recursive descent **from the root node**.

This means an expression starting with `//` will always search for occurences the *entire document*, even if it's called from a specific child note. That's why `SelectSingleNode` will always return the first match in the entire document.

To search relative to the node that calls the selection method there is the `.` operator which indicates the current context.

Put together, an expression starting with `.//` will search for all occurrences of the following pattern, *beginning at the current node*.

In the specific case, this means changing `//ns:` to `.//ns:` to get the expected result.